# Different admins for different instances

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to have different admin sites for different objects of the same model?

To be exact, I would like to have configurable "exclude" list for InlineAdmin, which would
allow me to select which fields are editable for given parent object instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would at field-permissons (to administrate it), and modify the admin page to check for permissions.

Someone else might have done this already.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to create a different admin site. I have solved similar problems by overwriting the get_queryset(...) method of admin.ModelAdmin. Try to look at the source code and see what methods you can overwrite to achieve your goal.